# Congratulations Kate Gregory on 100k!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations @KateGregory!

You have written some terrific answers over the years.

And so that this fits into a "question" format - what do you view as your "best" answer of all time?

Comment: Congratulations, @KateGregory! You also write terrific answers on other stacks - it's always a joy to read them!

Comment: Congratulations, Kate Gregory. Your answers have been extremely useful to me personally in navigating the workplace, not just in terms of the content but also the writing style.

Comment: *"what do you view as your "best" answer of all time?"* Voting to close as too broad. :)

Comment: Doesn't that make it POB rather than TB... @MaskedMan

Comment: @nij *pedant alert*: If the question is specifically addressed to Kate Gregory, it is primarily opinion based. However, since meta posts are addressed to the entire community, it is too broad because the community considers all her answers as the best. :)

Comment: @KageGregory is one of my favorite writers here!!  Congrats!!

Comment: Well done Kate..

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for noticing! It is a fun milestone.

I believe I like [How do I deal with the "30 minutes remaining" problem?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/how-do-i-deal-with-the-30-minutes-remaining-problem/89612#89612) the best. It's not my highest-voted, and not even the accepted answer on that question, but it's a useful piece of advice that applies across almost all occupations and at all levels in the management hierarchy. Because it's counter-intuitive, people are unlikely to discover it themselves, and instead can only learn it from someone they trust. The voting system here is one way readers can be told "I know this sounds wrong, but it actually works" and it's perfect for that answer.

I didn't expect this to be the site on which I had the most rep, but that's how it has turned out so far. Thanks to everyone for writing interesting questions that give us a chance to think about concepts we might otherwise take for granted, and to StackExchange for giving me a place to do some writing.

Comment: I absolutely loved this answer, and still follow your suggestion today!

Comment: Just became aware of that great answer. Excellent suggestions, will try to implement them ASAP! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: That's a great answer and it is very true. I've found I really NEED to do that, versus going home knowing what my next task was but having not started it at all. "Parking" it like that let's me mentally stop thinking about it, whereas if I don't start it at all, I end up thinking about it all night.